# Can't properly print file in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, text

I'm trying to `echo` the contents of [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/births/US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv) link and it exhibits what to me is bizarre behavior.

```
git@gud:/home/git$ URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/births/US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv"
git@gud:/home/git$ content=$(wget $URL -q -O -)
git@gud:/home/git$ echo $content
2003,12,31,3,12374_month,day_of_week,births
```

I expected this code to print the contents as I see them when I open the link on a browser. But instead, the output, on its entirety, is `2003,12,31,3,12374_month,day_of_week,births`, that's it.

I actually see this behaviour locally as well, after downloading the file. Tried it both using `curl` and simply copy and pasting into a text editor and saving the file. They all exhibit the same behavior. The same happens with `cat`, `cut`, `head`, `tail` and even `awk`.

This doesn't happen with other files and works fine on Python. What am I missing? How do I get it to work?

I realize that the file doesn't end with a new line character, but adding it doesn't fix it.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and the CLI I'm using is Bash release 4.4.19(1).

Comment: I have a hunch about what the problem is, but what behavior _do_ you actually see?

Comment: @DavidZ The output is `2003,12,31,3,12374_month,day_of_week,births`, that's it. Nothing more. It's the last line over a part of the first line.

Comment: Ah, I see. It would be useful to edit the question to mention that what you see is the last line over part of the first line - or alternatively, you could include the first and last couple lines in the question (maybe using `...` to indicate that the middle has been omitted). Try to make it so that, if someone is not able to access the file at the link, they can still understand what's going wrong.

Comment: @DavidZ That's actually the whole output. I hopefully have made this clear now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data file uses Mac-style end-of-line markers (carriage return only).  When you `echo` the content, or just `cat` the file, the lines are all printing over eachother.  If you were to view the file with `less` or `vim`, you would see the complete content.

Try this:

```
$ URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/births/US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv"
$ curl -o data.csv "$URL"
```

The `wc` command thinks that the file has zero lines:

```
$ wc -l data.csv
0 data.csv
```

Now let's translate those end-of-line markers:

```
$ tr '\r' '\n' < data.csv > data-modified.csv
```

`wc` now sees a more reasonable number of lines:

```
$ wc -l data-modified.csv
3652 data-modified.csv
```

And if we were to cat the file:

```
$ cat data-modified.csv
.
.
.
2003,12,28,7,7645
2003,12,29,1,12823
2003,12,30,2,14438
2003,12,31,3,12374
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a follow up question (let me know if this is stretching it), hopefully you can help me. When I read the file in Python, I see `\n`, not `\r`, so it was easy for me to dismiss it being a problem with the end of line character. See [here](https://pastebin.com/8vwQ822H). Why is this happening? What knowledge am I missing?

Comment: https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/newline-conversion-in-python-3/

Comment: Would it? I know that `tr` will be installed pretty much anywhere. That's less true for `mac2unix`.